# Responsive UI layout with grid layout

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

I have been struggling with the creation of a responsive UI layout which uses **GridLayout** to keep numbers in **TextViews**. I tried using **ConstraintLayout**, **Linear**, and **Relative** for the background and tried different values for the **TextViews** to align them. (The program should work with empty **TextViews** and on click to display a number(max 2digit number)). Here are images of the layout on different screen sizes: [This is the activity on Nexus 5(5,0inch)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrojD.jpg)

[and this is on Nexus 1(3,7inch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJleZ.jpg)

This is part of the xml at this moment(uploading only part of it because I got equal TextViews)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4">


</RelativeLayout>


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="34dp"
    android:paddingEnd="48dp"
    android:paddingTop="48dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:rowCount="5"
    android:columnCount="5">



    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    ></TextView>
```

Any ideas how can I properly align the grid and textviews so they work on any screen size? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use GridView where you can set a property `android:numColumns` to set number of coumns, and an custom adapter to set a content of each cell. Columns will be equal, if you  in yours adapter items will use `match_parent` width parameter.

Comment: @grabarz121 What exactly do you mean by custom adapter because I am not experienced and cannot understand you?

Comment: GridView needs as adapter class to fill yourself. [Here's](https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started) an example, how to do that. You can fill your adapter by empty strings, and change empty values by calling onItemClickListener on existing GridView layout item (for example using additional EditText to change value at a clicked position from a user input)

Answer (score -1):

Well I did fast scan of the code. Is the closing tag
`</GridLayOut>` missing!